# Android intent: Market/Play Store categories

Tags: android-intent

Taken from the Android Developer's site, it states that you are able to [link to a collection](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningCollection) on the Play Store by using the following uri construct:

```
market://apps/collection/<collection_name>
```

The table in the link above gives examples of `<collection_name>` to use:

```
market://apps/collection/editors_choice
```

The above fails with an activity not found exception.

I've therefore had to revert to the web url code and use the Play Store package name (if it's installed) to be able to do this.

```
Intent psi = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// psi.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/editors_choice"));
psi.setData(Uri.parse("market://apps/collection/editors_choice"));
// psi.setPackage("com.android.vending"); 
psi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(psi);
```

Can anyone else confirm that it's not working for them either or if am I missing something obvious...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @cmcromance - Unfortunately not. Still having to use the web url method detailed above.

Comment: Huh... The way we implemented is not even a trick. We should not have a problem from this. I don't know why... So bad. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you are getting activity not found exception.  Make sure you have defined in manifest . Remove this line **psi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);** from your code.